# How to use second argument (input) of system() function

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

The documentation to vim's `system` function says this about the second argument:

> When {input} is given, this string is written to a file and passed as stdin to the command.

What I understood from that was that if your `system` call looked like this:

```
call system('node something.js --file', 'here is some text')
```

The command executed would look like this:

```
node something.js --file some/temp/file
```

and `some/temp/file` would have the text `here is some text` as its contents. To test this, I ran the vim command (the second line is the result):

```
:echo system('cat', 'here is some text')
here is some text
```

Ok, that looks right. A second test:

```
:echo system('echo', 'here is some text')
<blank line>
```

Instead of getting some temporary file's name, I got a blank line. Moreover, when I print `process.argv` in my node.js script, I just get `['node', 'path/to/something.js', '--file']`.

What am I missing about how the `{input}` argument is to be used? How come it seems to work for `cat`, but not `echo` or my own script?

Comment: Hey downvoter. Mind telling my how I can improve my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got it wrong; the command executed is **not**

```
node something.js --file some/temp/file
```

but rather

```
echo "some/temp/file" | node something.js --file
```

or better

```
node something.js --file < some/temp/file
```

If you want text passed as arguments, just append this to the first argument of `system()` (properly escaped through `shellescape()`).