# Can I pass a string as stdin to a system call from vim?

Tags: stdin, vim

I want to run a system command from vim (`:help :!`), and I want to pass the contents of a string variable as stdin for that command.

I already know I can [pass lines from the current buffer as stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7867356/1523582) (see `:help :w_c`).  But I don't want to modify the current buffer, and I don't want to make a new buffer.

I know I can write the string to a temporary file, then pipe that file as input and delete it.  Right now, that's the best solution I know for my application.  But it would be cleaner to avoid creating the file in the first place.

Can it be done?

Comment: You'll find this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15579613

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so basically, you have a variable, say, a string, and you want to pass this variable to an external command, and get returned value in a variable instead of buffers.

If above is right, you could do in this way, see the following example:

```
let s="vim is good"
let r=system("sed 's/good/the best/'",s)
echo r
"display vim is the best
echo s
"display vim is good
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't actually care about the return value, but otherwise I think you understand what I want.  It looks like `system()` is the canonical vim way to do this.

Comment: @ChipHogg and you could build the command (the first arg of system() ) with the value (string) of your variable.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, here's another answer I figured out while hacking around.

@Kent's answer looks like the canonical vim way to pass stdin to a command.  It frees you from managing the temporary file.  But what if (for whatever reason) you want to avoid the overhead of creating a file at all?  Here's a way to do that.

The basic form is

```
echo your_string | your_command
```

Of course, getting the details right is highly error prone, so I recommend wrapping it in a function:

```py
function! RunCommandWithStdin(cmd, stdin_lines)
  let l:stdin = shellescape(join(a:stdin_lines, "\\n"), 1)
  execute '!echo -e' l:stdin '|' a:cmd
endfunction
```

Quick sanity check, using `patch`:

```
:!echo foo > bar
:!cat bar
foo
:call RunCommandWithStdin('patch bar', ['@@ -1 +1 @@', '-foo', '+~!@#$%^&*()'])
:!cat bar
~!@#$%^&*()
```

Note that this appears to be handling special characters correctly.

The downside is that it uses `echo`, so it's probably restricted to *nix-alikes.  Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass a list to system() to give your command more than one line of STDIN:

So:

```
let s=["perl is good", "perl is complicated"]
let r=system("sed 's/perl/vim/'", s)
echo r
"vim is good
"vim is complicated
```

Note also that in this case, you can use systemlist() to get your results as a list (as of Jan 2018, trailing blank lines are cut off, if this is important to you)

Comment: Another example you might do:

let s=getline(5,6) " grab lines from the buffer, etc... - as a list