# How do I send the current buffer or line as stdin to system() in vim?

Tags: shell, stdout, stdin, vim

There are 3 closely related vim commands that let you call an external program:

1. `:[range]!{filter-cmd} {arg}`  (ex-command, `:help :range!`)
2. `:[range]write !{cmd}` (ex-command, `:help :w_c`)
3. `system({expr}, {arg})` (vimscript function, `:help system()`)

(I'm including `!` and `:!cmd` as part of 1.)

From my view, there are three important distinctions:

1. `[range]` is sent to stdin in, stdout replaces `[range]`
2. `[range]` is sent to stdin, stdout is ignored
3. stdout is the return value of `system()`, so stdout can be saved to a variable as `:let @a = system(..)`

Is there really no way to send the current buffer or current line as stdin to an external command AND have unfettered access to stdout?

If you want to write, e.g., a complicated movement command that requires parsing of the line/buffer (parsing which would be better off not written in vimscript), this seems very surprising.

(Trying to send stuff through `{arg}` would be crazy for a couple reasons: 1. character length limits, 2. you'd have to write a shell escaping function from within vimscript*)

Here is the only other related question I could find.  It sends a string variable as shell arguments to (unix) 'echo', which then sends it as stdin to your program: [Can I pass a string as stdin to a system call from vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432409/can-i-pass-a-string-as-stdin-to-a-system-call-from-vim)

*If the vim function `shellescape()` does what you want, great, but on Windows it isn't even remotely robust for protecting input from `cmd.exe` and from `CommandLineToArgvW`.  In fact, on Windows vim sends any single shell string through `cmd.exe` *twice*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I was erring about one very important detail: the second argument to `system({expr},{input})` isn't treated as shell input, it is sent as stdin.  So you would do something like:

```
:let stdin = join(getline(1,'$'), "\n")
:let a = system('C:/main.exe',stdin)
```

Almost all examples of `system(..)` use and warn about shell escaping, but that is for the `{expr}` argument (and this escaping is a much smaller problem if `{expr}` is not a dynamic string).

Comment: If this answers the question, it’d be helpful if you could mark it Accepted so that the question doesn’t show up in Unanswered lists. :)

Comment: Instead of the line  `:let stdin = join(getline(1,'$'), "\n")`  you could use  `:let stdin = execute('%p')` .  However, you need to have the `number` setting turned off, or else `stdin` will contain line numbers.